# c# tabpage questions (disable headers/click events)

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

I thought I had this, but no. I have a 5 page tabcontrol. I have it so that when I click the tabpage4 ("Inventory") blank space, it adds things to a datagridview and rich textboxes. This only happens when I click on the page itself, and also duplicates with every subsequent click. I need to know...

-Is there a way of doing stuff when I click the tab, not the page itself?
-Can I make it so you can only click the tab once so as to prevent duplicates?

I had a look for the 2nd question, but they all disable the entire page - I need to be able to still use the controls inside the page.

I have;

```
void tabPage4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Add Stuff
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Just create a `bool` called `hasPopulated` and initially set it to `false`. First time you populate, set it to `true` and check its value on the `click` event.

Answer (score 0):

The correct method you should listen on is `SelectedIndexChanged`:

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hey!");
}
```

This gets fired everytime you change the tabpage, no matter in wich way, even if you use keyboard shortcuts.

Now, you can get the selected tabpage by looking at the `SelectedTab` property:

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You are viewing " + tabControl1.SelectedTab.Name);
}
```

Finally, you want to run your function only once, so you have to remember if you already run the code. You can create many variables or you can just use the `Tag` property (wich is there for you to store anything you want):

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag == null)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag = true; //set to true so no longer evaluates to null
        MessageBox.Show("You are viewing " + tabControl1.SelectedTab.Name);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sorry, can't run twice.");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

PS.: you can use a `switch` statement inside the `if` :)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer :) However, I only need it for the tabpage4, not the entire control so would I just replace "tabControl1" with "tabpage4"?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want attach dialogs dynamically to your tab pages, you could do it with the Selecting event, being triggered by clicking on the tab and before the tab page is displayed:

```
private void tabControl1_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage1)
    {
        //Attach only once
        if (tabPage1.HasChildren)
            return;
        myDialog1 dg = new myDialog1();
        dg.TopLevel = false;
        dg.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        dg.Parent = tabPage1;
        dg.Show();
    }
    else if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage2)
    {
        if (tabPage2.HasChildren)
            return;
        myDialog2 dg = new myDialog2();
        dg.TopLevel = false;
        dg.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        dg.Parent = tabPage2;
        dg.Show();
    }
    else if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage3)
    {
       //and so on
    }
}
```